# How to tell when a new MXD is opened

Tags: arcobjects, c#, arcgis-10.2

I am trying to force a tab from a tab container to open to a specific tab once a new MXD is opened. Currently it will stay on a previously selected tab when I use the catalog(docked) to open a new MXD. My question is how do I tell if a new MXD is loaded?

Thanks
-Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to listen to the [IDocumentEvents.NewDocument](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/NewDocument_Event/000v000000pv000000/) Event. There's a [snippet](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0049000000nq000000) available that shows how to wire this event.